# Java- Array creating a matrix based on the first two numbers of a read file

Tags: java

If I had a file text:

```
3@2/3@9@1
```

`@` and `/` are delimiters, 
The first two numbers will always be the size of the matrix

In order to code this I would have to run a while loop, then int row and column to equal the scanned text?

Comment: have you heard of `Split` function provided by java `String` class, Use that to split the content and pass your delimeters to it.

Comment: PLEASE do not downvote beginners. Just explain the problems of question in comments.

Comment: Check out the duplicate link. It is not exactly the same, but you should be able to use the example. Your sample data doesn't really make sense since there should be six data items for a 3x2 matrix.

Comment: @LalitVerma that's true. But some beginners do not read it. I asked to notice them with comments, not by downvote.

Comment: now this is well said @g.Irani

Answer (score 0):

First, split your text using the delimiter `"/"`:

```
String text = "3@2/3@9@1";
String[] splits = text.split("/");
```

Now, `splits[0]` includes `"3@2"` and `splits[1]` includes `"3@9@1"`.
Split the string `splits[0]` using the delimiter `"@"`:

```
String[] dims = splits[0].split("@");
```

String `dims[0]` is the row value `3` and `dims[1]` is the column value `2`.
Parse dims to integer in order to use them in construction of your matrix:

```
int r = Integer.parseInt(dims[0]);
int c = Integer.parseInt(dims[1]);
```

Create your matrix:

```
int[][] matrix = new int[r][c];
```